# Reference for good Android UI design patterns

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I would like to get some links for getting started with design patterns.My requirement is , (at Initial stage) How to go about developing a particular pattern , say customized ListView which can be shared across applications .

e.g. Applications will call something like drawCustomizedListView(params...) and my code will draw the listview according to the parameters supplied. This is particularly useful when across the applications I have to draw customized views.

My intention is,
I should not repeat the same code everywhere for doing similar task.

Any references for the above requirement ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the official video on `Android UI design patterns` of Google I/O 2010 event from here:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html

Also you can download PDF file of this:

http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-android-ui-design-patterns.pdf

And here you can find ultimate design patterns:

http://www.androidpatterns.com/

Comment: I have edited my answer to to reflect the changes what may you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create a package with a name such as com.yourcompany.android.ui.common and create all of your common classes in there. Build it as a .jar file and use it as an external reference in your android projects.

Comment: I will try this method , Thanks , any other approach ?